# Feasible way to find interpolating complex polynomial based on absolute value

Tags: polynomials, optimization, numerical-methods, interpolation, nonlinear-system

Consider a complex degree-$(n-1)$ polynomial $p(z) = \sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1} a_i z^i$.

1. Given a number $0 < m < 2n$ of positions in the complex plane with absolute value requirements, i.e. $|p(z_j)| \overset{!}{=} b_j$ (with $b_j \geq 0$), is there a practical algorithm to find the coefficients $a_i$ such that $p(z)$ satisfies those requirements? In other words, is there a way to solve a complex polynomial interpolation problem based only on given absolute values, leaving the argument (angle) of the polynomial completely arbitrary at any point?
2. How big can $m$ be for such an algorithm? In other words, how many degrees of freedom are gained by only specifying the absolute value instead of a "full" complex number consisting of an absolute value and an argument (angle)?

Comment: I have never seen an exclamation point placed above an equality sign. What does this combination of symbols mean? In any case, have you tried writing your problem as a real system of non-linear equations for a small value of $n$?

Comment: @CarlChristian My bad. This is indeed pretty nonstandard notation. It's supposed to mean "has to be equal to". It's basically still just an equality.
I have tried writing the equation system out for a small `n`. The equations are not at all straightforward to solve, which is why I asked the question here. The best algorithms I have found so far that can actually solve this in a practical way are optimization algorithms (differential evolution etc.). Since these generally have exponential complexity, they do not scale well. My `n` is usually something like 1024.

Comment: In truth, I do not see an alternative to doing a non-linear solve. I suspect that it will be important not to use square roots needlessly and solve $p_j \bar{p}_j = b_j^2$. It might be useful to know what your specific application is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the simple case of $n = 2$, it turns out to be rather trivial to find $m = 3$ conditions $|p(z_j)| \overset{!}{=} b_j$ that no polynomial of degree $1$ can satisfy. Hence, $m$ can not be greater than $n$ in the general case. There are however some (not so rare) examples of conditions which can be satisfied.

For $m \leq n$, the polynomial can easily be found by choosing a random argument (angle) for each $b_j$ and then solving the resulting system of linear equations. Since a polynomial only exists in some special cases when $m > n$, an algorithm to find that polynomial for arbitrary conditions cannot exist. There still might be a way to determine the space of conditions that yield a polynomial and a corresponding algorithm, though.